# Show that $\iota_{*}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\right)=-\sum_{j}\left(g_{i j} \circ \iota^{-1}\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}^{*}}$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with standard affine coordinate system. We note by $\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{N}}^{*}$ the dual of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ endowed with the standard affine connection $D^{*}$ and $\left\{x_{1}^{*}, \cdots, x_{n}^{*}\right\}$.
We called by the Hessian domain the triple $(\Omega, D, g=D d \varphi)$ such that $\Omega$ is a domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $(D, g=D d \varphi)$ the Hessian domain on $\Omega$ that is, $g_{i j}=\frac{\partial^{2} \varphi}{\partial x^{i} \partial x^{j}}$.

The gradient mapping for the Hessian domain $(\Omega, D, g=D d \varphi)$ is a locally bijective map from $\Omega$ into $\mathbb{R}_{n}^{*}$ defined by $$\iota=-d \varphi,$$
show that :
$$
\iota_{*}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\right)=-\sum_{j}\left(g_{i j} \circ \iota^{-1}\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}^{*}}, \quad \iota_{*}^{-1}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}^{*}}\right)=-\sum_{j} g^{i j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}}$$
I know how to compute the pushforward of a vector field but in this case iI don't n=know what to do !  Any help is really appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What part of the computation is giving you trouble? You said you know how to compute the pushforward of a vector field. The formula you posted for $\iota_*(\partial/\partial x^i)$ is just the standard formula for the pushforward (see my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, formula (8.7) and Example 8.20), together with the fact that the Jacobian of the map $\iota$ is equal to minus the Hessian of $\varphi$, which in turn is equal to $-g_{ij}$. The second formula is obtained from the first by applying $\iota_*^{-1}$ to both sides and multiplying by the inverse of $(g_{ij})$.

Comment: Thank you Mr Lee ! I really appreciate your help !